# Play Framework 2.2 subprojects

Tags: java, git, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm trying to add a subproject to my Play Framework project, and find the docs generally lacking there.

I've created a play project, let's call it `my-web`, and it's in directory `/my-cool-project/web`. I also have another project I would like `my-web` to depend on, let's call it `my-model`. `my-model` a git submodule for `my-cool-project`, and when I pull it, my directory structure is

```
/my-cool-project
     /my-web
         /app
         /conf
         build.sbt
     /my-model
         /main
              /java
                   /src
```

Now, how do I add `my-model` as a subproject for `my-web`? I've tried

```
lazy val myModel = project.in(file("../my-model"))
```

but all I get is that `my-model` is not contained within the build root of `my-web`... Anything else I can try in build.sbt?

Comment: A subproject is expected to reside in a subdirectory of the main project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

project is used to define the project model and sub-projects. For sibling project, you can use RootProject or ProjectRef. In your case, I would use RootProject.

```
lazy val myModel = RootProject(file("../my-model"))
```

When you compile a project, compilation on all RootProjects and ProjectRefs will triggered as well. You will define your project setting for my-model inside the build file in my-model project. This reduce the duplication for the project definition.

Think about RootProject and ProjectRef like project reference in Eclipse.

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

change `lazy val myModel = project.in(file("../my-model"))`
 
to

`lazy val myModel = project.in(file("my-model"))`

Path it refers is from root of the project. So, you can give this path accordingly.